# 作ったテキストファイルに文字が入らない

Tags: python, python3, 文字コード

以下のように入力して作ったファイルに英単語テストを書きたかったのですが、生成したテキストファイルを開いてみたらエラーが出ていました。

この場合どうしたら対応できるのでしょうか。環境はJupyter Notebookです。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Error! C:\Users\Ryotaro Arakawa\programming\英単語テスト_01.txt is not UTF-8 encoded
Saving disabled.
See Console for more details.
```

**ソースコード**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import random

source = 'english_words.txt'

with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    english_words = [l.strip() for i, l in enumerate(data) if ((i%2) == 0)]
    jp_meanings = [l.strip() for i, l in enumerate(data) if ((i%2) != 0)]

words_dict = dict(zip(english_words,jp_meanings))

print(words_dict)

n_tests = 5
n_questions = 50
for test_num in range(n_tests):
    with open('英単語テスト_{:02d}.txt'.format(test_num +1),'w') as f:

        f.write('第{}回英単語テスト\n\n'.format(test_num +1))

        for question_num in range(n_questions):
            question_word = random.choice(english_words)
            correct_answer = words_dict[question_word]

            meanings_copy =jp_meanings.copy()
            meanings_copy.remove(correct_answer)
            wrong_answers = random.sample(meanings_copy,3)

            answer_options = [correct_answer] + wrong_answers

            random.shuffle(answer_options)

            f.write('問{}. {}\n\n'.format(question_num + 1,question_word))

            for i in range(4):
                f.write('{}.{}\n'.format(i + 1, answer_options[i]))
            f.write('\n\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずはエラーメッセージのとおりに、書き込み用ファイルの`open`時にも`encoding='utf-8'`を指定してみましょう。
これを：

```
with open('英単語テスト_{:02d}.txt'.format(test_num +1),'w') as f:
```

こうしてみてください。

```
with open('英単語テスト_{:02d}.txt'.format(test_num +1),'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

それと、エラーメッセージに`See Console for more details.`とあるので、Jupyter NotebookのConsoleに何かメッセージが出ているでしょう。
そちらも読み取って質問に追記してみてください。
その内容によっては別の対処が必要になるかもしれません。

Comment: エラーメッセージ的には「このファイルは UTF-8 ではないよ」と言っているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうです。「 **生成した** テキストファイルを **開いて** みたらエラーが出ていました。」というのですから、ファイルを作る際のencoding指定がおかしいのでしょう。